# How to prevent slugs from invading the alley and stairs?

Tags: safety, slugs

The end of the rainfall season and the rising temperatures do not prevent them from taking a walk on the paved alley and even climbing the stairs! Even after watering the garden and keeping the alley dry, they head up to their adventure.

I have never been bothered by slugs, but stepping on one is a slipping hazard, especially when using the stairs.

**EDIT:** Added photo & info
The slugs seem to exit the garden and into the path when I water the plants. This may look strange, as they prefer their more humid locations in the hot summer and would better to stay in the garden.
They come out at night. Nothing stays on the paved area during the day.
[image]

Comment: do you have a photo of the area?

Comment: Are these regular slugs or West Coast Banana Slugs?

Comment: Sounds like you need better lighting.  You can prevent reproduction by salting them in the early evening when they are basking on the pavement.  Sometimes mulch or wood chips are a factor.  Also damp, dark conditions.

Comment: If you have a dry sheltered area nearby you can place bait there.